# function `any()` applied to several arrays rather than just one

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, numpy-ndarray

I want to apply the function `any()` to all the rows of a matrix at the same time.

If I use `any()` with a vector, of course it will return `True` (or `1` in my case) whenever any element would return `True`:

```
import numpy as np

print any(np.array([0,0,0,1]))*1
```

Now suppose I have a matrix instead. If I want to obtain a vector with `1` and `0` depending on whether each element of the matrix would return `True` when taken alone, I can do it with a `for` loop:

```
matrix=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
result=np.zeros(len(matrix)).astype('int')
i=0
for line in matrix:
    result[i]=any(matrix[i])
    i+=1
    

print result
```

However, this method does not seem very practical, because the elements of the matrix will be handled once at a time with the `for` loop. Is there a better way to extend `any` to a matrix input, in such a way that it returns a vector of several `1` and `0` as above?

Note that I do not want to use `matrix.any()` because it will just return a single `True` or `False` statement, whereas I want it to be applied to each individual element of the matrix.

Comment: Please provide some expected input/output as your goal is not very clear. `any` is not "applied" to anything nor it returns a vector. It merely returns `True` or `False` whether  an element in the iterable it was provided with is truthy

Comment: If all you want is a row of 1s if any element in the row is truthy, maybe `np.where` can help.

Comment: @DeepSpace TY. Yes I would like to obtain the same output as in what I wrote but without using the `for` loop. Probably `np.where` is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numpy.any(matrix, axis=1)
```

`numpy.any` already has the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
matrix_sums = np.sum(matrix, axis=1)
are_truthy_matrix_sums = matrix_sums > 0

print are_truthy_matrix_sums
```

We use `np.sum` to simplify the matrix to a 1D array with the sums, before comparing these sums against 0 to see if there were any truthy values in these rows.

This prints:

```
[False  True  True]
```

Comment: You're working along the wrong axis - you just didn't notice because both `axis=0` and `axis=1` happen to produce the same result for this array.